# Format Table Column Widths to Fit Content (No Wrapping)

Tags: html, css, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I'm using the newest version of Visual Studio with an ASP.NET MVC site with Entity Framework. I'm trying to make columns on the index view tables expand with the text inside rather than wrapping text. Is this possible to do?

Here's an example:
[image]

I want to be able to prevent wrapping and simply expand the table and column size and prevent text wrapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `white-space: nowrap;` css property on the table cells you dont want to wrap text in.

**[Update]**

For bootstrap use the class `text-nowrap` that is already there in bootstrap. e.g.

```
<td class='text-nowrap'> Your content here </td>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there something in the bootstrap.css somewhere for that?

Comment: Can you please share a sample code so that we know what you are using and what solution would be best. You asked for table text not wrapping which indicated your using <table>. You did not mention anything of bootstrap. Share a sample code with your problem using codepen or jsfiddle and share the link so that we can check and give you solution for it.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include the bootstrap solution.